# Is there a way to undelete a deleted row in INFORMIX-SQL?

Tags: sql, informix, delete-row

Other than physically removing the \0 at the end of the row with a text editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the data server behind Informix SQL.

If the data server is SE (Standard Engine), and if the wind is blowing in your favour (in particular, if the space previously allocated to the now deleted row has not yet been reused for anything else), then you could modify the `.dat` file to change the 'dead row' marker (`'\0'` in C) into the 'live row' marker (`'\n'` in C).  You would then need to check the indexes on the table with `bcheck` or `secheck` (depending on the version of Informix SE).  This relies on some internal knowledge about C-ISAM data files.

If the data server is IDS (Informix Dynamic Server, aka Informix these days), then the answer is substantially 'no'.  Certainly, the 'space not reused' caveat applies.  However, there isn't a simple end of row marker as in C-ISAM (SE), and there isn't an easy way to find exactly where the deleted data was stored, and there are problems with rows split over multiple pages for big enough row sizes (bigger than 4 KiB; on most systems, bigger than 2 KiB), etc.  Substantially, therefore, the answer is no.